# How to add text before existing text

Tags: vps

Hello I would like to add the word: tarvell: before each word on every line.
The file is 1Gb so I would like to be able to do it through my VPS if possible.
Im guessing some sort of grep/awk program could do it. Thanks.

Current:
Line1
Line2
Line3

Want:
tarvellLine1
tarvellLine2
tarvellLine3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Q:  Im guessing some sort of grep/awk program could do it

A: Yes, indeedy.

I'm guessing your VPS is probably running Linux (or a close *nix variant), and that you have a command prompt (e.g. a putty terminal).

Try "sed".

EXAMPLE:

```
# Create input file
vi tmp.txt
  abc
  def
  geh

# Add "tarvell" to the beginning of each line; write to a second file
sed 's/^/tarvell/' tmp.txt > tmp2.txt

# Print the results
cat tmp2.txt
  tarvellabc
  tarvelldef
  tarvellgeh
```

Answer (score 0):

`sed 's/\(^\|\W\)\(\w\)/\1tarvell\2/g' -i` *filename*

original

```
one two
 three (four), five
```

updated

```
tarvellone tarvelltwo
 tarvellthree (tarvellfour), tarvellfive
```